# Manually creating a HTTP SOAP Request with Signing SOAP messages using X.509 certificate

Tags: web-services, soap, netsuite

I am trying to send a message from NetSuite to another system via http SOAP, but I was told that I have send a signed soap message.  NetSuite only has an operation called nlapiRequestURL(url, postdata, headers);  I am trying to use this method to send over a manually created SOAP message.  What I am having problems with is figuring out how to add the cert to the header.  Has anyone does this before?

What I have learned about signing a soap message with the certificate is that I need private key and public in the local keystore.  This tutorial in java shows how to do it, but how would I do something similar in NetSuite.

https://dzone.com/articles/signing-soap-messages

Comment: If your SOAP endpoint is https, shouldn't the implementation logic of https handle it implicitly? Can you point to the documentation of SOAP API authentication,  probably we could help more?

Comment: From what I have seen in the java example is that I need to have the private key and public to generate a signed soap message.  So, I was using the cert from the NetSuite url  system.sandbox.netsuite.com.  I am sure that NetSuite isn't  going to give me their private key, so most likely they need to generate a private and public key.  Then associate it with their CA cert.  Then it sounds like they need to give me some api access to use there keystore to generate the signed soap message.

Comment: would your SOAP service provider be okay with a self-signed certificate or it relies on trusted CA only? this guy seems to have used self signed certificate http://www.john-james-andersen.com/blog/service-now/tutorial-soap-into-servicenow-via-x509-ws-security.html for a WS

Comment: The provider wants a CA cert

Comment: see my answer for a solution as netsuite won't give their certificate's private key's access

Answer (score 0):

> One possible solution is you write your own proxy web server in Java
>   or any other server side language for that matter.

Below is the summary of my suggestion:

> 1) Send the request details from NetSuite to proxy server using a
>   Suitelet or scheduled script.
>
> 2) In the proxy server create the signed SOAP request and send to the
>   vendor API
>
> 3) Now, to respond back to NetSuite there are two options    a) you
>   keep the connection open with NetSuite until you get the response and
>   send it back to NetSUite's script   b)you respond back to a NetSuite
>   RESTlet, which makes the design asynchronous and can be good specially
>   if the turn around time is more than 45 seconds.

Also, I would suggest to write web server using HTTPS, with your server having a trusted CA signed certificate, so, that communication between web server and NetSuite is secure. And this way your communication would be secure (P.S. I can't answer the question that is SSL 100% secure, there are good discussion on http://security.stackexchange.com on that topic).